# TypeError: cannot x object en python

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pickle

Quiero serializar en un archivo el objeto de una clase(esta clase es la que contruye la GUI) con pickle, pero me da el siguiente error

```
File "f:/La_gloria/Programa de escritorio/ProgramaEscritorioLaGloria/Menu_principal.pyw", line 255, in <module>
    mp.setupUi(mp)
  File "f:/La_gloria/Programa de escritorio/ProgramaEscritorioLaGloria/Menu_principal.pyw", line 219, in setupUi
    pickle.dump(menuPrincipal,f)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'MenuPrincipal' object
```

El codigo que serializa el objeto en el archivo es:

```
 with open("datos","wb") as f:
     pickle.dump(menuPrincipal,f)
```

El archivo se crea, pero no me serializa y por ende no escribe los datos.
¿Porque pasa esto? ¿Que puedo hacer?
adjunto el codigo de la ventana principal
Lo que necesito serializar en un archivo es la el objeto vp y el ojeto logeo. Porque al momento en que el usuario se ha creado(esto esta en otro archivo dentro de una clase) es ese archivo que debe ejecutar una función para mostrar el menu principal y el usuario no deba logearse

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pickle
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from sys import argv,exit
from Logica.Logicalogging import LogicaLog
from logging1 import FormularioLogeo
from detalles_Turnos import Turnos
from Logica.detalleTurn import detalleTurno
from productos import VentanaProductos
from informes import Informe
from Creacion_del_usuario import CuentaUsuario
from Logica.objetos import DatosClases

class MenuPrincipal(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):  
    def __init__(self, parent=None): 
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent) 
        self.productos = VentanaProductos()
        self.productos.setupUi1(self.productos)
        self.informe = Informe()
        self.informe.setupUi(self.informe)

    def ventanaTurnos(self,deporte): 
        if(deporte == "fútbol"):
            Turnos.depo = "futbol"
        elif(deporte == "Pileta"):
            Turnos.depo = "pileta"
        elif(deporte == "Paddle"):
            Turnos.depo = "paddle"

        Turnos.nombreEtiqueta = deporte
        tns = Turnos()
        detalleTurno.ventana = tns
        detalleTurno.mostrarVentana(self)
        
    def setupUi(self, menuPrincipal):
        menuPrincipal.setObjectName("menuPrincipal")
        menuPrincipal.resize(739, 609)
        menuPrincipal.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(70, 70, 70);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(menuPrincipal)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.comboBoxDeportes = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.comboBoxDeportes.setFont(font)
        self.comboBoxDeportes.setObjectName("comboBoxDeportes")
        self.comboBoxDeportes.addItem("")
        self.comboBoxDeportes.addItem("")
        self.comboBoxDeportes.addItem("")
        self.comboBoxDeportes.addItem("")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.comboBoxDeportes)
        self.reservasHechas = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.reservasHechas.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.reservasHechas.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(106, 106, 106);")
        self.reservasHechas.setLineWidth(7)
        self.reservasHechas.setAutoScrollMargin(1)
        self.reservasHechas.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
        self.reservasHechas.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.reservasHechas.setObjectName("reservasHechas")
        self.reservasHechas.setColumnCount(5)
        self.reservasHechas.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.reservasHechas.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.reservasHechas.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.reservasHechas.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.reservasHechas.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.reservasHechas.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        self.reservasHechas.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(400)
        self.reservasHechas.horizontalHeader().setHighlightSections(False)
        self.reservasHechas.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(200)
        self.reservasHechas.verticalHeader().setCascadingSectionResizes(True)
        self.reservasHechas.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(79)
        self.reservasHechas.verticalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(69)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.reservasHechas)
        menuPrincipal.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.barraMenu = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(menuPrincipal)
        self.barraMenu.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 739, 37))
        self.barraMenu.setObjectName("barraMenu")
        self.itemArchivo = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.barraMenu)
        self.itemArchivo.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.itemArchivo.setSeparatorsCollapsible(True)
        self.itemArchivo.setObjectName("itemArchivo")
        self.menuReservasDeTurnos = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.itemArchivo)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.menuReservasDeTurnos.setFont(font)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Imagenes Frella/calendario.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.menuReservasDeTurnos.setIcon(icon)
        self.menuReservasDeTurnos.setObjectName("menuReservasDeTurnos")
        self.itemBar = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.barraMenu)
        self.itemBar.setObjectName("itemBar")
        self.itemInforme = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.barraMenu)
        self.itemInforme.setObjectName("itemInforme")
        menuPrincipal.setMenuBar(self.barraMenu)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(menuPrincipal)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        menuPrincipal.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.subitemCerrar = QtWidgets.QAction(menuPrincipal)
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Imagenes Frella/4115235-exit-logout-sign-out_114030.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.subitemCerrar.setIcon(icon1)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.subitemCerrar.setFont(font)
        self.subitemCerrar.setObjectName("subitemCerrar")
        self.subitemBar = QtWidgets.QAction(menuPrincipal)
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Imagenes Frella/bar_icon_150144.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.subitemBar.setIcon(icon2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.subitemBar.setFont(font)
        self.subitemBar.setObjectName("subitemBar")
        self.subitemTurnos = QtWidgets.QAction(menuPrincipal)
        icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Imagenes Frella/olimpycs_17_icon-icons.com_68623.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.subitemTurnos.setIcon(icon3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.subitemTurnos.setFont(font)
        self.subitemTurnos.setObjectName("subitemTurnos")
        self.subitemProductos = QtWidgets.QAction(menuPrincipal)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.subitemProductos.setFont(font)
        self.subitemProductos.setObjectName("subitemProductos")
        # self.subitemOfertas = QtWidgets.QAction(menuPrincipal)
        # font = QtGui.QFont()
        # font.setPointSize(14)
        # self.subitemOfertas.setFont(font)
        # self.subitemOfertas.setObjectName("subitemOfertas")
        # self.subitemProductosLiquidados = QtWidgets.QAction(menuPrincipal)
        # font = QtGui.QFont()
        # font.setPointSize(14)
        # self.subitemProductosLiquidados.setFont(font)
        # self.subitemProductosLiquidados.setObjectName("subitemProductosLiquidados")
        # self.actionCanchaDeBasquet = QtWidgets.QAction(menuPrincipal)
        # self.actionCanchaDeBasquet.setObjectName("actionCanchaDeBasquet")
        self.actionGimnasio = QtWidgets.QAction(menuPrincipal)
        icon4 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon4.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Imagenes Frella/pesa.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionGimnasio.setIcon(icon4)
        self.actionGimnasio.setObjectName("actionGimnasio")
        self.actionPileta = QtWidgets.QAction(menuPrincipal)
        icon5 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon5.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Imagenes Frella/-pool_90362.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionPileta.setIcon(icon5)
        self.actionPileta.setObjectName("actionPileta")
        self.actionCanchaDeFutbol5 = QtWidgets.QAction(menuPrincipal)
        icon6 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon6.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Imagenes Frella/campo-de-futbol.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionCanchaDeFutbol5.setIcon(icon6)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.actionCanchaDeFutbol5.setFont(font)
        self.actionCanchaDeFutbol5.setObjectName("actionCanchaDeFutbol5")
        self.actionCanchaDeTenis = QtWidgets.QAction(menuPrincipal)
        icon7 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon7.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Imagenes Frella/tennis_86305.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionCanchaDeTenis.setIcon(icon7)
        self.actionCanchaDeTenis.setObjectName("actionCanchaDeTenis")
        self.menuReservasDeTurnos.addAction(self.actionCanchaDeFutbol5)
        self.menuReservasDeTurnos.addAction(self.actionGimnasio)
        self.menuReservasDeTurnos.addAction(self.actionCanchaDeTenis)
        self.menuReservasDeTurnos.addAction(self.actionPileta)
        self.itemArchivo.addAction(self.menuReservasDeTurnos.menuAction())
        self.itemArchivo.addAction(self.subitemCerrar)
        self.itemBar.addSeparator()
        #self.itemBar.addAction(self.subitemProductosEnStock)
        #self.itemBar.addAction(self.subitemOfertas)
        self.itemBar.addAction(self.subitemProductos)
        self.itemInforme.addAction(self.subitemBar)
        self.itemInforme.addAction(self.subitemTurnos)
        self.barraMenu.addAction(self.itemArchivo.menuAction())
        self.barraMenu.addAction(self.itemBar.menuAction())
        self.barraMenu.addAction(self.itemInforme.menuAction())
        
        #eventos
        self.actionCanchaDeFutbol5.triggered.connect(lambda: self.ventanaTurnos("fútbol"))
        self.actionPileta.triggered.connect(lambda: self.ventanaTurnos("Pileta"))
        self.actionCanchaDeTenis.triggered.connect(lambda: self.ventanaTurnos("Paddle"))
        self.actionGimnasio.triggered.connect(lambda: self.ventanaTurnos("Gimnasio"))
        self.subitemProductos.triggered.connect(self.productos.show)
        self.subitemBar.triggered.connect(self.informe.show)
        self.subitemTurnos.triggered.connect(self.informe.show)
        
        self.retranslateUi(menuPrincipal)
        menuPrincipal.destroyed.connect(menuPrincipal.close)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(menuPrincipal)
    
    def retranslateUi(self, menuPrincipal):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        menuPrincipal.setWindowTitle(_translate("menuPrincipal", "Menu principal"))
        self.comboBoxDeportes.setItemText(0, _translate("menuPrincipal", "Fútbol"))
        self.comboBoxDeportes.setItemText(1, _translate("menuPrincipal", "Paddle"))
        self.comboBoxDeportes.setItemText(2, _translate("menuPrincipal", "Gimnasio"))
        self.comboBoxDeportes.setItemText(3, _translate("menuPrincipal", "Natación"))
        item = self.reservasHechas.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("menuPrincipal", "Cliente"))
        item = self.reservasHechas.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("menuPrincipal", "Total a pagar"))
        item = self.reservasHechas.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("menuPrincipal", "Horario"))
        item = self.reservasHechas.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("menuPrincipal", "Cant. de horas reserbadas"))
        item = self.reservasHechas.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("menuPrincipal", "Atendido por"))
        self.itemArchivo.setTitle(_translate("menuPrincipal", "Archivo"))
        self.menuReservasDeTurnos.setTitle(_translate("menuPrincipal", "Reservas de turnos"))
        self.itemBar.setTitle(_translate("menuPrincipal", "Bar"))
        self.itemInforme.setTitle(_translate("menuPrincipal", "Informe"))
        self.subitemCerrar.setText(_translate("menuPrincipal", "Salir"))
        self.subitemBar.setText(_translate("menuPrincipal", "Bar"))
        self.subitemTurnos.setText(_translate("menuPrincipal", "Turnos"))
        self.subitemProductos.setText(_translate("menuPrincipal", "Productos"))
        #self.actionCanchaDeBasquet.setText(_translate("menuPrincipal", "Cancha de basquet"))
        self.actionGimnasio.setText(_translate("menuPrincipal", "Gimnasio"))
        self.actionPileta.setText(_translate("menuPrincipal", "Pileta"))
        self.actionCanchaDeFutbol5.setText(_translate("menuPrincipal", "Cancha de fútbol 5"))
        self.actionCanchaDeTenis.setText(_translate("menuPrincipal", "Cancha de paddle"))


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(argv)
mp = MenuPrincipal()
mp.setupUi(mp)
if True:
    mp.hide()
    logeo = FormularioLogeo()
    obj.ventanaLogeo = logeo
    CuentaUsuario.ventanaLogeo = logeo
    LogicaLog.ventanaPadre = logeo
    LogicaLog.menuPrincipal = mp
    logeo.setupUi(logeo)
    logeo.show()
exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Que raro, puedes añadir la clase y el objeto que estás intentando guardar por favor.

Comment: @RubialesAlberto No todas las clases son *pickables* asi que no es raro.

Comment: Isaias si deseas ayuda entonces debes proveer un [MRE] como señalan las reglas de SO

Comment: Llevas razón! Gracias @eyllanesc por el comentario!  Gracias a el, he podido encontrar [What can be pickled and unpickled?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) y aprender algo nuevo :)

Comment: @eyllanesc ya subi el código